# Fragment Null pointer on BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I'm trying to replace the map Fragment with a new fragment that has a plot markers. However, I am having a null pointer after I click the date where it replace the Fragment. Any help? Thanks.

```
  custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(getActivity(),
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                                  Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                                  String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                                  String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                                  int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM) {
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
                    String i_hr = df.format(hour24);
                    String i_min = df.format(min);
                    String i_sec = df.format(sec);
                    String i_monthNumber = df.format(dateSelected.getMonth()+1);
                    String i_calendar_day = df.format(dateSelected.getDay()-1);

                    dateFrom = (i_monthNumber)
                            + "/" + (i_calendar_day) + "/" + year
                            + i_hr + ":" + i_min
                            + ":" + i_sec;

                        SnailTrailFragment stf;
                        stf = new SnailTrailFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager;
                        manager = manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, stf).commit();

                }
```

Stack trace of error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at com.journeytech.mark.mark.BottomSheetModalFragment$2$1.onSet(BottomSheetModalFragment.java:88)
>                                                        at com.journeytech.mark.mark.CustomDateTimePicker.onClick(CustomDateTimePicker.java:278)
>                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4560)
>                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18636)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post  the stack trace of crash

Comment: Hi, SripadRaj.. Pls. check

Comment: What is at line 88 of that file?

Comment: Is `manager = manager = getFragmentManager` a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the support Fragment Manager with AppCompatActivity

```
final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

CustomDateTimePicker custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(getActivity(),
        new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

             ... 
             Fragment stf = new SnailTrailFragment();
             manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainLayout, stf)
                .commit();
```